# Android: how to check if LauncherActivityInfo is the main activity

Tags: android, android-activity, package, icons, launcher

I've forked the AOSP Launcher source and I'm trying to edit the getIcon method from the icon provider.

I need to know whether a "LauncherActivityInfo foo" is the main activity for an application.

I currently do

```
if (foo.getLabel().toString().equals( foo.getApplicationInfo().loadLabel(mContext.getPackageManager()).toString() )
```

where mContext is my application Context

But it doesn't always work as sometimes it will have a different label even though it's the main activity; any solution?

Comment: What do you mean by "different label"? Different from what? Do you take into account that apps can declare more than one launcher activity?

Comment: That's exacly what I'm trying to check, i need to know whether some activity is the app's main activity or not

Comment: there is no such thing as *Main activity* in Android.

Comment: @VladyslavMatviienko what about android.intent.action.MAIN or android.intent.category.DEFAULT? Aren't used to assign an activity as default?

Comment: Yes, you are right.

Comment: What do you mean by "main activity"?

Comment: You can set ACTION=MAIN on as many activities as you want. What are you trying to do here?